# Adapting html site

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

Hy!
I want to make my html and css page resize when the user changes the size of
the browser's window and i want to make the page adapt to different resolutions.
I've tried some answers here in this site,but they don't work for me.
i also tried to use media queries

Here it is the css and the html

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
body{
 font-family: 'Francois One', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 color: white;
 text-align:center;
 background:black;
 
}
.corpo{
 margin-top: 5px;
 margin-left:  400px;
 margin-right: 250px;
 float:middle;
 
}
header{
 margin: 40px 0;
}
.menu li{
 display: block;
 float: left;
 width: 125px;
 height: 50px;
 line-height: 50px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #2C3E50;
 border-right: 1px solid #2C3E50;
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFFF00 50%, #FFFF00 51%, #f6f6f6 100%);
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFFF00 50%, #FFFF00 51%, #f6f6f6 100%);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #FFFF00 50%, #FFFF00 51%, #f6f6f6 100%);
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #FFFF00 50%, #FFFF00 51%, #f6f6f6 100%);
 border-color:black;
 opacity:1;
 position:relative;
}
.menu li:hover{
 cursor: pointer;
 background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #ffffff 0%, #e5e5e5 100%);
 background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #ffffff 0%, #e5e5e5 100%);
 background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #ffffff 0%, #e5e5e5 100%);
 background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #ffffff 0%, #e5e5e5 100%);
 color: slateGrey;
 border-color:black;
 position:relative;
}
.primo{
 border-top-left-radius: 10px;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}
.ultimo{
 border-top-right-radius: 10px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
.sub-menu{
 visibility: hidden;
}
.menu li:hover .sub-menu{
 visibility: visible;
}
.sub-menu li{
 border-top: 1px dotted #2C3E50;
}
.sub-menu li:hover{
 width: 145px;
 background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #f7fbfc 10%, #add9e4 100%);
 background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #f7fbfc 10%, #add9e4 100%);
 background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #f7fbfc 10%, #add9e4 100%);
 background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #f7fbfc 10%, #add9e4 100%);
 transition: all 0.1s ease 0s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease 0s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease 0s;
 -o-transition: all 0.1s ease 0s;
 -ms-transition: all 0.1s ease 0s;
}
.ultimo-sub{
 border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}

.menu li a:link{
color:black;
text-decoration:none;
}

.menu li a:hover{
color:black;
text-decoration:none;
}

.menu li a:active{
color:black;
text-decoration:none;
}

.menu li a:visited{
color:black;
text-decoration:none;
}

p{
 color: #FFFF00;
 margin: 0px 380px 0px 400px;
 font-size:150%;
 text-shadow: 2px 0 0 #000, 0 -1px 0 #000, 0 2px 0 #000, -1px 0 0 #000;               //text-shadow: 2px 0 0 #000, 0 -1px 0 #000, 0 2px 0 #000, -1px 0 0 #000;
 
}

.Paragrafo{
 text-shadow:1px 0 0 #000, 0 -1px 0 #000, 0 1px 0 #000, -1px 0 0 #000;
 size:25px;
}

.Paragrafo  a:link{
color:yellow;
}

.Paragrafo a:hover{
color:yellow;
}

.Paragrafo  a:active{
color:yellow;
}

.Paragrafo  a:visited{
color:yellow;
}

h1{
 color:blue;
 
}

span{
 color: #FFFF00;
 margin: 0px 380px 0px 400px;
 font-size:150%;
 text-shadow: 2px 0 0 #000, 0 -1px 0 #000, 0 2px 0 #000, -1px 0 0 #000;               //text-shadow: 2px 0 0 #000, 0 -1px 0 #000, 0 2px 0 #000, -1px 0 0 #000;
 
}

.video{
 position: 404 532;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Menù a tendina in HTML e CSS</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="new 1(!).css">
  <style> h1 {color:yellow;
              float:center;
             } </style>     
 </head>      
  <body>
 
  
   <header>
    <h1>La Grande Guerra</h1>
   </header>
  <div class="corpo">
   <ul class="menu">
    <li class="primo"><a href="SitoHome2(!).html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="1914.html">1914</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="1915.html">1915</a>
     <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="1915-1.html">Da 01 a 04</a></li>
      <li><a href="1915-2.html">Da 05 a 08</a></li>
      <li class="ultimo-sub"><a href="1915-3.html">Da 09 a 12</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="1916.html">1916</a>
     <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="1916-1.html">Da 01 a 04</a></li>
      <li><a href="1916-2.html">Da 05 a 08</a></li>
      <li class="ultimo-sub"><a href="1916-3.html">Da 09 a 12</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="1917.html">1917</a>
     <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="1917-1.html">Da 01 a 04</a></li>
      <li><a href="1917-2.html">Da 05 a 08</a></li>
      <li class="ultimo-sub"><a href="1917-3.html">Da 09 a 12</a></li>
     </ul>
       </li>
    <li><a href="1918.html">1918</a>
     <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li class="ultimo-sub"><a href="1918-1.html">Eventi</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Armistizio</a>
     <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li class="ultimo-sub"><a href="#">Conseguenze</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="Galleria.html">Galleria</a>
     <ul class="sub-menu">
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="ultimo"><a href="Fonti.html">Fonti</A></li>
    
   </ul>
  </div> <BR> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> 
  <div class=Paragrafi>
  <p>
  
          TEXT
          
  <object class=video width="420" height="315"data="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6FgaL0xIazk?list=PLB2vhKMBjSxOb_127vxjaRRC7yu2TJlJX"
  float=left align=right>
        </object>
  </p>
          
  <p align=left>
          
          TEXT
   
  </p> 
   

  
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can try using some ready made CSS frameworks like bootstrap for efficient responsive web design

Comment: Hy Jones , can you write me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the viewport meta tag.

---

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

---

Now it should work using media queries. You can check out this url for more details : http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: m a noob at coding, so can you make an example relatable to my needs?

Comment: This is not created by me but it might help you understand what I am trying to say. http://jsfiddle.net/DrSRT/

Comment: Nikhilesh I've encountered a problem.                 If a put more queries only the lastest i've added to the code works.                                                                         ex. @media screen and (min-width:761px) and i add another the latest will work

Comment: Yeah you need not add it each and every time. add it only once and have multiple class declarations like @media (min-width:500px) {body{background-color:blue;} div{font-size:15px;}}

Comment: i mean  @media screen and (min-width:761px)  and another media screen of a different resolution (ex min-width 761 px and then another one of 900 px)

Comment: You shouldn't have it like this. You can probably have something like min-width: 761px and max-width:900px and another as min-width:901px. Both styles will work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

add this in your css sheet

```css
/*
  Based on:
  1. http://stephen.io/mediaqueries
  2. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/
*/

/* iPhone 6 in portrait & landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 375px) 
and (max-device-width : 667px) {
  
}

/* iPhone 6 in landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 375px) 
and (max-device-width : 667px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
  
}

/* iPhone 6 in portrait */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 375px) 
and (max-device-width : 667px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
  
}

/* iPhone 6 Plus in portrait & landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 414px) 
and (max-device-width : 736px) {
  
}

/* iPhone 6 Plus in landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 414px) 
and (max-device-width : 736px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
  
}

/* iPhone 6 Plus in portrait */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 414px) 
and (max-device-width : 736px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
  
}

/* iPhone 5 & 5S in portrait & landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 568px) {
  
}

/* iPhone 5 & 5S in landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 568px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
  
}

/* iPhone 5 & 5S in portrait */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 568px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
  
}

/* 
  iPhone 2G, 3G, 4, 4S Media Queries
  It's noteworthy that these media queries are also the same for iPod Touch generations 1-4.
*/

/* iPhone 2G-4S in portrait & landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
  
}

/* iPhone 2G-4S in landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
  
}

/* iPhone 2G-4S in portrait */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
  
}

/* iPad in portrait & landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px)  {
  
}

/* iPad in landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
  
}

/* iPad in portrait */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
  
}

/* Galaxy S3 portrait and landscape */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 320px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

}

/* Galaxy S3 portrait */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 320px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) 
  and (orientation: portrait) {

}

/* Galaxy S3 landscape */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 320px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) 
  and (orientation: landscape) {

}

/* Galaxy S4 portrait and landscape */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 320px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) {

}

/* Galaxy S4 portrait */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 320px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) 
  and (orientation: portrait) {

}

/* Galaxy S4 landscape */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 320px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) 
  and (orientation: landscape) {

}

/* Galaxy S5 portrait and landscape */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 360px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) {

}

/* Galaxy S5 portrait */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 360px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) 
  and (orientation: portrait) {

}

/* Galaxy S5 landscape */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 360px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) 
  and (orientation: landscape) {

}

/* HTC One portrait and landscape */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 360px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) {

}

/* HTC One portrait */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 360px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) 
  and (orientation: portrait) {

}

/* HTC One landscape */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 360px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) 
  and (orientation: landscape) {

}

/*
  iPad 3 & 4 Media Queries
  If you're looking to target only 3rd and 4th generation Retina iPads 
  (or tablets with similar resolution) to add @2x graphics,
  or other features for the tablet's Retina display, use the following media queries.
*/

/* Retina iPad in portrait & landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  
}

/* Retina iPad in landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  
}

/* Retina iPad in portrait */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  
}

/*
  iPad 1 & 2 Media Queries
  If you're looking to supply different graphics or choose different typography 
  for the lower resolution iPad display, the media queries below will work 
  like a charm in your responsive design!
*/

/* iPad 1 & 2 in portrait & landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
  
}

/* iPad 1 & 2 in landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
  
}

/* iPad 1 & 2 in portrait */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) 
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
  
}

/* iPad mini in portrait & landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
  
}

/* iPad mini in landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {

}

/* iPad mini in portrait */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
  
}

/* Galaxy Tab 10.1 portrait and landscape */
@media
  (min-device-width: 800px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1280px) {

}

/* Galaxy Tab 10.1 portrait */
@media 
  (max-device-width: 800px) 
  and (orientation: portrait) { 

}

/* Galaxy Tab 10.1 landscape */
@media 
  (max-device-width: 1280px) 
  and (orientation: landscape) { 

}

/* Asus Nexus 7 portrait and landscape */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 601px) 
  and (device-height: 906px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.331) 
  and (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio: 1.332) {

}

/* Asus Nexus 7 portrait */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 601px) 
  and (device-height: 906px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.331) 
  and (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio: 1.332) 
  and (orientation: portrait) {

}

/* Asus Nexus 7 landscape */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 601px) 
  and (device-height: 906px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.331) 
  and (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio: 1.332) 
  and (orientation: landscape) {

}

/* Kindle Fire HD 7" portrait and landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 800px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1280px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {

}

/* Kindle Fire HD 7" portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 800px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1280px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) 
  and (orientation: portrait) {
    
}

/* Kindle Fire HD 7" landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 800px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1280px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) 
  and (orientation: landscape) {

}

/* Kindle Fire HD 8.9" portrait and landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 1200px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1600px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {

}

/* Kindle Fire HD 8.9" portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 1200px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1600px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) 
  and (orientation: portrait) {
    
}

/* Kindle Fire HD 8.9" landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 1200px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1600px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) 
  and (orientation: landscape) {

}

/* Laptops non-retina screens */
@media screen 
  and (min-device-width: 1200px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1600px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
    
}

/* Laptops retina screens */
@media screen 
  and (min-device-width: 1200px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1600px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (min-resolution: 192dpi) {
    
}

/* Apple Watch */
@media
  (max-device-width: 42mm)
  and (min-device-width: 38mm) { 

}

/* Moto 360 Watch */
@media 
  (max-device-width: 218px)
  and (max-device-height: 281px) { 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you're missing the [viewport tag](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp) in your HTML:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

I recommend to use a front-end Framework like Bootstrap or Foundation to handle this and make your site ready for any device.